# adjusting dynamic form to work with multiple sections

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamic, addition

I have a script which dynamically adds rows to a form with default values:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var defaults = {
    'name[]':           'Name',
    'email[]':          'Email',
    'organisation[]':   'Organisation',
    'position[]':       'Position'
};

var setDefaults = function(inputElements, removeDefault)
{
    $(inputElements).each(function() {
        if (removeDefault)
        {
           if ($(this).data('isDefault'))
           {
            $(this).val('')
                   .removeData('isDefault')
                   .removeClass('default_value');
           }
        }
        else
        {
            var d = defaults[this.name];
            if (d && d.length) 
            {
                this.value = d;
                $(this).data('isDefault', true)
                       .addClass('default_value');
            }
        }
    });
};

setDefaults(jQuery('form[name=booking] input'));

$(".add").click(function() {
                var x = $("form > p:first-child").clone(true).insertBefore("form > p:last-child");
    setDefaults(x.find('input'));

                return false;
            });

            $(".remove").click(function() {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });

// Toggles 
$('form[name=booking]').delegate('input', {
    'focus': function() {
       setDefaults(this, true);
    },
    'blur': function() {
       if (!this.value.length)    setDefaults(this);
    }
});
 });
```

For the following form:

```
<form method="post" name="booking" action="bookingengine.php">
                <p><input type="text" name="name[]">
                 <input type="text" name="email[]">
                <input type="text" name="organisation[]">
                <input type="text" name="position[]">
                <span class="remove">Remove</span></p>

                <p><span class="add">Add person</span><br /><br /><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" /></p>

</form>
```

I would now like to split the form into 2 sections, each of which can have rows added dynamically to it.  The second section would only have spaces for name and email, so the form as a whole, before any additional rows are added, would look something like this:

[image]

But I'm not sure how to achieve this.  Either I would create a separate form with a seperate script, and then would need to know how to submit the information from both forms together, or I would just have one form but would then need to work out how to add rows dynamically to each section.

Could someone help with this?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've implemented this in a [fully functional example here](http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/sPP9z/3/).

I cleaned up your code a little bit, but it's basically the same. The main addition is that I wrapped the inputs in a `fieldset` element (you could use a `div` just as well, but `fieldset` is the semantically correct element for grouping related input fields). Your 4-input section lives in one `fieldset`, and your 2-input section lives in another; the "Add Person" handler looks for the parent `fieldset`, clones the first child, and adds it into that fieldset. Conveniently, in your use case the defaults for the first `fieldset` are the same as those for the second `fieldset`, but it would be easy enough to set up multiple sets of defaults and pass them into the `setDefaults` function.

A few other changes to the code:

- I split your `setDefaults` function into two different functions, `setDefaults` and `removeDefaults` - you weren't gaining anything by making them a single function, and splitting them makes the code more legible.
- I used `.delegate` to assign the "Remove" handler - otherwise the "Remove" button wouldn't work for new input sets. I also created the "Remove" button with jQuery, rather than cloning it, because I assumed that it wouldn't make sense to include it for the first input set.
- I used jQuery in a couple of places where you were using raw Javascript (e.g. getting and setting input values). I generally assume that jQuery is more reliable for cross-browser DOM access and manipulation, so if you're loading the library already there's rarely any point *not* using it for all but the simplest DOM functions.
- I removed your `.data` calls, since you can get the same information by inspecting the class, and it's generally better to reduce complexity. It's possible that `.hasClass('test')` is slightly slower than `.data('test')`, but I don't think it should make any difference here.

Comment: Thanks for your very instructive and helpful answer.  Just what I was looking for.  Nick

Answer (score 1):

Create one form.  Put two divs inside of it.  Have your script add/remove form elements to the appropriate div.

When you submit the form it should automatically submit all of the form elements in both divs since the divs are contained in the form.